# Add new array object in existing key value without change - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In our application, when user register first time I need to save user key and its value. So first time I am created successfully like this format;

```
key: "ayi927GHt548"
 data: {
 userdata: [
    {classId: "001", updateDate:"2018/02/12"}
 ]}
```

for this I get the class id and update date like this; here is the code

```
 -(void)someMethod {
   // ... do the process to get user class ID and user key
   userClassID = @"001" // string declared global
   userKey = @"ayi927GHt548" // string declared global

   [apiManager saveUserInformationwithKey:userKey andValue:[self saveCurrentUserIformationIntoUserInfoAPI]];

 }

   -(NSDictionary *)saveCurrentUserInformationIntoUserInfoAPI {

      NSDictionary *dictionaryUserInfo = @{
      @"userData": @[
          @{
              @"classId": userClassID, // I get user class id 
              @"updateDate": [self getCurrentDateTime]
           }
        ]
     };
  return dictionaryUserInfo;
}
```

// in global apimanager class i have a method to added on key value for get final solution

```
-(void)saveUserInformationwithKey:(NSString *)key andValue:(NSDictionary *)value {
     NSDictionary *authInform = @{
        @"key": key,
        @"value": value
     };

   // call api for post method
 }
```

this much I did correctly as what I want.

but the problem is for another case I need to append the new value to same existing 'userdata', without change the previous one, that is look like;

```
   key: "ayi927GHt548"
   data: {
       userdata: [
            {classId: "001", updateDate:"2019/02/18"},
            {classId: "003", updateDate:"2019/02/21"} //? here this is the new object is which i want to add
      ]
   }
```

how can I get like this? please help

currently Iam doing like this

```
    NSMutableArray *dataFinal =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"]];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:5] ;
    [dict setObject:@"54455" forKey:@"classId"]; 
    [dict setObject:[self getCurrentDateTime] forKey:@"updateDate"]; 
    [dataFinal addObject:dict];
    NSLog(@"Final: %@", dataFinal);
```

and the response look like this, but I need to append inside userdata

```
{
    key = 12345;
    data =         {
        userdata =             (
                            {
                updateDate = "2019/02/21";
                classId = 0002;
            }
        );
    };
},
    {
    updateDate = "2019/02/21";
    classId = 54455;
}
```

Comment: from where you want to update the `userdata`, please include that part also.

Comment: you should create mutable copy of your array you want to append, Now append element in newArray and then reAssign old array with you new array :)

Comment: @Akhilrajtr as same method only i need to update with new class id and cureent date

Comment: @AbuUlHassan where I need to create a mutable copy

Comment: on what place you want to append?

Comment: I'm sorry
I don't think we can solve problems for the sake of solving them, any more than we can work for the sake of working. Although the answer can solve the questioner's problem, I think it will be very inconvenient to design a data structure to save User data in the future. A mutable dictionary should be used to contain the Array in the outermost layer of the mutable Array, with the Key as UserId and the Value as the Array of the object of User. I hope I can help you

Comment: Data Flow Design Issue: You are using dictionary instead of custom object.

Comment: Hi can you explain how to solve this problem? I know its difficult to parse

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the value and append it to the array later.

```
NSMutableArray *userData = [dictionaryInfo objectForKey:@"userData"]; 
NSDate *yourdate = date; 
NSNumber *classID = classID; 
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:5];
[dict setObject:classID forKey:@"classId"]; 
[dict setObject:yourdate forKey:@"updateDate"]; 
[userData addObject:dict];
```

I am away from my mac, please kindly correct semantic errors yourself. :)

**EDIT:**
I have added the code to be in your userData, try to add this line and tell me?

```
dataFinal = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKeyPath:@"data. userdata"]mutableCopy];
```

Print the values and let me know.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi the app crashing after I did like this [__NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. In the line addObject

Comment: Check if your addObject variable is nil, it could be the reason.

Comment: Did you try my approach? This error your getting because your dictionary is not mutable.

Comment: @Lije edit your question, i will help you, add the current code what you are trying?

Comment: hi I updated my question currently doing in last flow

Comment: hi now its working, but append data is out of 'userData' array

Comment: Check Edit and try adding this and comment out the datafinal values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get `userData` array and then convert it in mutable array of dictionaries.

Then you need to append the required data in `userData` and then save back to user defaults.

Comment: so before api call I need to get all userData  right?

Comment: When you are ready to store data in user defaults then you need to do it.

Comment: convert it in mutable array of dictionaries which mean MutableDictionary right?

Comment: `userData` is an array which contains multiple dictionaries. First `userData` will be converted in mutable array and append a dictionary in `userData` array.

Comment: hi crashed [__NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance I

Comment: You need to make it `NSMutableDictionary`  and then add object in it. It is crashing becoz the dictionary is immutable i.e. `NSDictionary`.